# Keyboard won't appear in modal view controller

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in a modal view controller (using [SVModalViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController)). In iOS 4.2, when I tap on an input text field, the keyboard does not appear. The view animation where the page scrolls to make room for the keyboard still happens, but nothing appears. It works fine in iOS 5.

I am calling `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` in the application delegate, so that is not the issue.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Similar to this unanswered question: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1630764?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I needed to make the view controller containing the UIWebView the first responder, and after that, it worked!